# Python Not Web Linking Entire variable in str.ljust

Tags: python, text

I have Python code that pulls info from a sqlite database and then write to a html file. I'm trying to write as preformatted text and the code below places the text in columns like I am try to accomplish, but (obviously) the link is the entire length of the string, including the whitespace to the right from the .ljust.

How can I get it to only link the text of `item.title` instead of the entire string, plus whitespace?

```
content += '<a href="/%s/">%s</a>  %s' % (item.slug, str(item.title).ljust(25), item.date.ljust(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *must* do it on one line, the following should work for you:

```
content += '<a href="/%s/">%s</a> %s  %s' % tuple(itertools.chain((item.slug,),
           str(item.title).ljust(25).split(" ", 1), (item.date.ljust(10),)))
```

However the following should be a little easier to read

```
values = [item.slug]
values += str(item.title).ljust(25).split(" ", 1)
values.append(item.date.ljust(10))
content += '<a href="/%s/">%s</a> %s  %s' % values
```

Notice I've added one extra space to your formatting string to make up for the one lost to the string split operation.

---

EDIT: The above code fails when `item.title` is greater than 25 characters.  A revised version is below.

```
title, spaces = (str(item.title).ljust(25)+" ").split(" ", 1)
content += '<a href="/%s/">%s</a>%s  %s' % (item.slug, title, 
                                            spaces, item.date.ljust(10))
```

This version adds a space to the end of the justified title, so the split operation is guaranteed to return a tuple of length 2.

Answer (score 1):

Edit

```
title = str(item.title)
spaces = ' '*(25-len(title)) if len(title) <= 25 else ''
'<a href="/%s/">%s</a>%s  %s' % (item.slug, title, spaces, item.date.ljust(10))
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't word the question best. I need/want the whitespace, the whitespace is created by .ljust

I'm trying to move the .ljust aspect of the string after the </a> not before that closing tag

Comment: @Jason give an example of what you're getting and what you want.

Comment: Here are the examples...

Correct: http://s29509.gridserver.com/correct.html
Incorrect: http://s29509.gridserver.com/incorrect.html

Just the link on the Incorrect goes the entire length of the ljust for the team name

Comment: Oh, now I see. I'll change my answer